# Change phpmyadmin settings in Jelastic MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, jelastic

I need to change the phpmyadmin settings in my Jelastic MySQL install. The issue is that phpmyadmin is in /var/lib/phpMyAdmin and I don't have access into that folder and thus cannot change its configuration file. When I enter the MySQL host in my Jelastic structure I can't see the base folder and navigate to them. The folders available through config feature in Jelastic or FTP are "cron", "scripts", "keys", "conf.d", "etc", "backup".

Folder "conf.d" has the file "phpMyAdmin-jel.conf" but it won't allow me to change any phpmyadmin settings.

Comment: Can you clarify which settings you want to change exactly / why (what problems you're experiencing with the current settings)?

Comment: I need to import a huge database file (~600MB). Uploading the file through regular http on phpmyadmin regular 'Import' admin interface simply won't do. It will eventually timeout or my session on phpmyadmin will expire. I want to approach this another way. I want to upload the database file through FTP to the phpmyadmin upload folder. But I can't reach the phpmyadmin upload folder because I simply can't reach it. It points to a path I don't have access to.

Comment: At Layershift, you can also ask support to have any phpmyadmin settings changed. That's how I managed to enable phpmyadmin configuration storage. That could be similar at other hosters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that this part of the default Jelastic MySQL / MariaDB templates should be improved; users should be given access to modify this part of the conf in future (even better, more appropriate default configs should be set).

But in the meantime a better way to approach this would be to upload the file via SSH (scp) as described in the documentation here: http://docs.jelastic.com/ssh-access#direct-access

After adding your public SSH key in the Jelastic dashboard, you can SSH directly to any node in your environment (even without any public IP) using this format:

ssh {nodeid}-{uid}@{SSH_gateway} -p 3022

After the file transfer is complete you can just import it directly on the command line, using the mysql command.

Comment: Damien, thanks a lot, this was really helpful. Running all these steps to circumvent those limitations is annoying.